# Symfony2 LexikFormFilter bundle custom filter

Tags: php, symfony, filter

I have an entity named **`Product`** with a `name` property.

For a product named **"Red Light Saber"** for example, I would like to be able to get it as a result when I type *"Saber"* or *"Red"* in the filter text field.

But actually, I need to type exactly *"Red Light Saber"* for the product to appears.

I'm using [LexikFormFilterBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/working-with-the-bundle.md). To solve my problem, I try to do what the documentation explain in section **iv. Filter customization**.

This my `ProductFilterType.php`

```
<?php

namespace ProjectList\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Query\QueryInterface;

class ProductFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public $choices;

    public function __construct($providers)
    {
        foreach ($providers as $provider) {
            $this->choices[$provider->getId()] = $provider->getName();
        }
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'filter_text', array('apply_filter' => function (QueryInterface $filterQuery, $field, $values)
            {
                if (empty($values['value'])) {
                    return null;
                }

                $paramName = sprintf('p_%s', str_replace('.', '_', $field));

                // expression that represent the condition
                $expression = $filterQuery->getExpr()->eq($field, ':' . $paramName);
                var_dump($expression);
                die;

                // expression parameters
                $parameters = array($paramName => $values['value']); // [ name => value ]
                // or if you need to define the parameter's type
                // $parameters = array($paramName => array($values['value'], \PDO::PARAM_STR)); // [ name => [value, type] ]

                return $filterQuery->createCondition($expression, $parameters);
            },
            ))
            ->add('description', 'filter_text')
            ->add('type', 'filter_choice', array(
                'choices' => array(0 => 'Gadget', 1 => 'Textile')
            ))
            ->add('provider', 'filter_choice', array(
                'choices' => $this->choices,
            ));

        $listener = function (FormEvent $event) {
            // Is data empty?
            foreach ($event->getData() as $data) {
                if (is_array($data)) {
                    foreach ($data as $subData) {
                        if (!empty($subData)) return;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!empty($data)) return;
                }
            }

            $event->getForm()->addError(new FormError('Filter empty'));
        };
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, $listener);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'projectlist_bundle_entitybundle_productfiltertype';
    }
}
```

This is my var_dump($expression) of line 40 result :

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison)[620]
  protected 'leftExpr' => string 'e.name' (length=6)
  protected 'operator' => string '=' (length=1)
  protected 'rightExpr' => string ':p_e_name' (length=9)
```

I think I have to change the operator for something like `contain` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to act as a SQL LIKE statement you simply do as follow:

```
        ->add('name', 'filter_text', 'filter_text', array('condition_pattern' => FilterOperands::STRING_BOTH));
```

As you can see in the [source code here](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/blob/d6081d308b71e14509602722c78d28801e4ed78a/Filter/Doctrine/Expression/ExpressionBuilder.php#L163) and described [here in the doc](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/provided-types.md)

Hope this help

Comment: It works ! thank you @Matteo.

If other people have the same "issue", in the solution there is a 'filter_text' parameter that should be removed and don't forget to `use Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\FilterOperands;`

Comment: STRING_BOTH is now deprecated, use STRING_CONTAINS if needed